# Adding Data into A map field (Flutter Firestore)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloud_firestore for flutter .I want to add onto a map field (userInfo) of a specific document of my firebase database on the press of a button. I do not want to add  any other fields, only append more data to the map(userInfo).In this case using this code name is always unique (the userID) of a user.

```
    Firestore.instance.collection("prayerRooms")
              .document(docID)
              .updateData({

              'userInfo.userId': name,
              'userInfo.userCount': 2


          }
          );
```

[image: Here is the database in question]

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
 Firestore.instance.collection("prayerRooms")
              .document(docID)
              .updateData({
              'userInfo.userId': name,
              'userInfo.userCount': 2
          });
```

will update both the `userId` and the `userCount` inside the `userInfo` map. If you want to add more attribute inside the `userInfo` map, then you can do:

```
 Firestore.instance.collection("prayerRooms")
              .document(docID)
              .updateData({
              'userInfo.users': "user1",
          });
```

This will add a new attribute inside the map called `users`.

Comment: Oh,no don't want to add another attribute, I want to add more data into the userId and userCount of the map. So every time I press the button with a different user, it should add that user's data into the userCount and userId field.It should keep the previous data , not overwrite it or update it.

Comment: every time you press the button with a different user, you should create a different document and not add it to the map, the max document size is 1mb, if every time a different user presses the button and you add to the map then the application wont scale

Comment: Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits

Comment: Yes, I have read it. My app (at least starting off) will be limited to only a few users(30 or less).

Comment: Yes still u need to do it correctly from the beginning, each user should have thier own document

Answer (score 1):

You can user `SetOptions(merge: true)` for that

Full code:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("prayerRooms")
      .document(docID)
      .set({
        'userInfo.userId': name,
        'userInfo.userCount': 2
      },
      SetOptions(merge: true),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

2023:

```
 FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 db.collection("collection")
   .doc("DOC-ID")
   .update({
     'userInfo.users': "user1"
   });
```